# jQuery Fancybox video is downloading not playing

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to have a video play in a fancybox, but what is happening the video is downloading. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
    $('a.video').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
       $.fancybox({
             type' : 'iframe',
            // hide the related video suggestions and autoplay the video
            'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp('watch\\?v=', 'i'), 'embed/') + '?rel=0&autoplay=1',
            'overlayShow' : true,
            'centerOnScroll' : true,
            'speedIn' : 100,
            'speedOut' : 50,
            'width' : 640,
            'height' : 480
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click function may be overriding the call on fancybox. You should call `.fancybox()` directly on the link.

```
<li><a class="video fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/L9szn1QQfas?autoplay=1">My Video</a></li>

$('.video').fancybox();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bevanr01/s7mLkn9j/

Comment: @KevinDavis : quick answer, yes depending on what type of videos. If you are playing mp4 videos, I would recommend you to use the [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) plugin. I wrote a tutorial about it http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/ ... you still can use the same code to play youtube videos (check the comments below the tutorial for instructions)

Comment: Yes, should be same concept. Just be sure `href` is pointing to correct location.

Comment: Sounds good @KevinDavis If it works, please accept my answer. I'm tired of not being able to comment on other answers and I only need +2 reputation!

Comment: @JFK I apologize for the comments. I'd really appreciate it if you could remove the down vote from my post as it has no good reason for being there now.